# Is the BODY field important in redirected URL?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo

I am running a wordpress site on which i was trying some redirects. I noticed when i redirect a particular URL from .HTACCESS the header response has a body of something like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://example.com/aaa/bbb/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips DAV/2 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at example.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

But the same is not appearing when i redirect a URL with wp_redirect().

Will that affect anything from a SEO perspective?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [RFC2616 for HTTP1.1, section 10.3.2](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) "301 Moved Permanently":

> Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity of the response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the new URI(s).

Which I read as meaning it has body content, if its a `GET` request.

As to how Google and others interpret the 301, this may help to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19645542/695787 . There are many discussions of this on the internet, but as far as I know, Google does not have a published specification for it.